# body_class() outputting classes to page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-theme

I have a custom WP page and want to be able to target different page id classes. When I add body_class() to the header `<body>` section it outputs all classes to the page!

I also have a gtag Google Analytics script tag at the start of the header but I don't think that should affect it.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>


<meta name="google-site-verification" content="Ey9SSwK6cHm5KMRuCUinWcWx1URGF8FZ8FV5HnG2B4A" />
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <title>The Carnivore Diet - The Ultimate Diet for Weight loss, Digestion and Inflammation!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was I had to have body_class() in the body tag:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```